# People Results Showing Old Employees

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a simple Employee Directory built using the Out of the Box search center.

```
https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/search/Pages/peopleresults.aspx?k=%2A
```

However, it is showing old employees that left months ago. Are these results bound to Active Directory? How do we clean it up?

Comment: Are you synchronizing accounts to Azure AD using AD connect or are they cloud only accounts?

Comment: The are Cloud only accounts @sssreddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those users are coming from local AD to SPO online thru the sync service -  this is a known issue, for that we need to follow the below :

Need to change the profiles AD property “msExchHideFromAddressLists” to True Or Yes for all disabled users.

```
  set-adobject -Identity $someoneDisabledUser -replace @{msexchhidefromaddresslists="$true"}
```

And if the users are from office 365 not from local AD, then just restrict this in the search query, change the text from

```
  {searchboxquery} to {searchboxquery} AND -“SPS-HideFromAddressLists”:1
```

For detailed steps refer the below :

https://global-sharepoint.com/2019/10/26/hide-disable-or-inactive-users-from-sharepoint-online-search/